# Unlock content without InAppPurchase

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

My need is to unlock the content for users who buyed a tangible product, being more specific, a book.

In fact the app will be complementary, not the main product. The first idea is to ship an unlock code inside each book.

Knowing that InAppPurchase is the common method to unlock content in iOS apps and knowing that Apple could see this as workaround to avoid InAppOurchase, I'll like to ask if someone has already did this sucessfully without any problems in respect to Apple approval.

Unlocking content WITHOUT InAppPurchase conform to App Store rules?

Comment: Mhh... why don't you write an email to Apple Developer Support? I think, they can answer your question directly :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that you app is very likely to be rejected if you decide to make such an unlocking feature, according to Apple's Guidelines

```
11.1 - Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
```

So, you'd better not try to do that this way.

Comment: What if the same content is made available as InAppPurchase too?

`11.13 Apps can read or play approved content (magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video)
that is sold outside of the app, for which Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues,
provided that the same content is also offered in the app using IAP at the same price or less
than it is offered outside the app. This applies to both purchased content and subscriptions.`